# SOAP character encoding

Tags: php, soap, character-encoding

I've built a webservice in php/soap, but I'm running into trouble when sending special characters through soap. Is there any way to specify what encoding to use with soap? Do you have to do it in the wsdl file or the client and server scripts?

Comment: Which characters are you having trouble with? "Special" for you might not be the same as "special" for me.

Comment: Swedish å ä ö characters. I know what charset to use but not where to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

`$options["encoding"] = "iso-8859-1";

$server = new SoapServer("siebelid.wsdl", $options); //and same for client`

Above did it